# swipl(prolog compiler) giver Undefined procedure error, but the rule is already defined

Tags: prolog, runtime-error, dijkstra, swi-prolog

I've recently started learning prolog for an assignment.

The question asked to find a time optimized route from A to B.

I defined edges and rules like following

```
bus(12,panbazar,chandmari,10,12.5,7,8).
bus(22,chandmari,paltanbazar,17.5,18,9,10).
bus(32,chandmari,paltanbazar,13,14.5,11,12).
```

## # Edge definitions

```
edge1(A, B, Departure, Arrival, Dist, Cost) :-
    bus(_, A, B, Departure, Arrival, Dist, Cost),
    Time is Arrival-Departure, Time > 0.

edge(A, B, Time, Dist, Cost) :-
    bus(_, A, B, Departure, Arrival, Dist, Cost),
    Time is Arrival-Departure, Time > 0.
```

Here bus rule represents `bus(BusId, From, To, Departure, Arrival, Distance, Cost)`.

When querying in swipl `edge(chandmari, Q, W, E, R)`. returns result

but when querying `edge1(chandmari, Q,W,E,R,T)`. I get the following error.

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: edge1/6
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         edge/5
false.
```

Comment: Does the interpreter raises any warnings. If you for example forget a `.` in the previous clause, then this can be interpreted as part of the body.

Comment: It looks like you have not successfully loaded the definition of `edge1/6`. As @WillemVanOnsem points out, an error in a clause above won't prevent a clause below from being processed, so just because the independent predicate `edge/5` works doesn't mean the whole file was processed successfully.

Comment: I'm aware of that WillemVanOnsem. The code that I pasted here is the exact same as in the file. @DanielLyons Are you saying there is an error in my code? If so, can you please guide me to what it is, I'm inexperienced in prolog.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. Maybe exit Prolog and load it again? Read the messages it prints closely. If that doesn't help, I can't help further unless you post the rest of the code.

Comment: @DanielLyons Currently this is all the code that I have in my file (I isolated this code to debug it), the message given here is the full error that is displayed by swi-prolog complier. I use command `swipl -i "filename".pl` to reload the compiler each time I make changes to the file.

Comment: It would be sufficient to type `swipl` and then `[filename].` to load it once running. Subsequently, you would type `make.` whenever you change the file to cause SWI to reload it. But I don't see anything wrong with this data that would explain the behavior you're seeing. Are you sure the file you're editing is the file you're loading? At this point you may need in-person assistance since there isn't much more I can do to help you with a basic error arising seemingly from thin air.

Comment: @DanielLyons I removed the comment "# Edge definitions" in my file and the code is working now, weird :/ . Thanks for helping me out :).

Comment: That's not how you make a comment in Prolog. :) Instead you must use `%` or `/* */`. And I would be fairly confident that SWI croaked at you about it.

Comment: Also, that would be the kind of thing I could spot _if_ you include the whole source... which is why we ask people to do that and include the error, so we can be more helpful with less back-and-forth.